CallbackRouteError {"provider": "credentials"} I don't understand why
I have this error and I can't find any solution on the Internet.
Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev/#credentialssignin
[auth][error] CallbackRouteError: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#callbackrouteerror
[auth][cause]: Error
at Module.callback (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/callback/index.js:226:23)
at async AuthInternal (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@auth/core/lib/index.js:66:24)
at async Auth (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:126:34)
at async signIn (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./node_modules/next-auth/lib/actions.js:51:17)
at async $$ACTION_0 (webpack-internal:///(action-browser)/./src/actions/login.ts:30:9)
at async C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:39:418
at async rS (C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:38:7978)
at async r2 (C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:41:1251)
at async doRender (C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1438:30)
at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1599:28)
at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1507:28)
at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1924:24)
at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1962:32)
at async DevServer.pipeImpl (C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:920:25)
at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:272:17)
at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:816:17)
at async C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:339:20
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:154:20)
at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:336:24)
at async requestHandlerImpl (C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:377:13)
at async Server.requestListener (C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\Project-L\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:141:13)
[auth][details]: {
"provider": "credentials"
}
Here's the code for the various files.
"use server"

import * as z from 'zod';
import { AuthError } from "next-auth";

import { signIn } from "@/auth";
import { LoginSchema } from '@/schemas';
import { DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT } from "@/routes";

export const login = async (values: z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>) => {
    const validatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(values);

    if(!validatedFields.success){
        return {error: "Invalid fields"}
    }

    const { email, password } = validatedFields.data;

    try {
        await signIn("credentials", {
            email,
            password,
            redirectTo: DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        if(error instanceof AuthError){
            switch (error.type) {
                case "CredentialsSignin":
                    return {error: "Invalid credentials"}
                case "CallbackRouteError":
                    return {error: "An error occurred with the callback route"}
                default:
                    return {error: "An error occurred"}
            }
        }

        throw error;
    }

};

import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth"
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials"

import { LoginSchema } from "@/schemas"
import { getUserByEmail } from "@/data/users";

export default {
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            async authorize(credentials: any ) {
                const validateFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(credentials)

                if(validateFields.success) {
                    const { email, password } = validateFields.data


                    const user = await getUserByEmail(email);
                    if (!user || !user.password) return null;

                    const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
                        password,
                        user.password
                    );

                    if(passwordsMatch) return user;
                }

                return null;
            }
        })
    ]
} satisfies NextAuthConfig

Connexion issue
When I try to log in normally I must have {error: "Invalid credentials"} because my input data is not correct and I have everything but that.
I use Next.js and auth v5

I had the same problem, I was using next-auth: 5.0.0-beta.19, I installed 5.0.0-beta.4 and it worked. I'm unsure what was causing the error.
If you find another solution share it please.
